# Unable to open a 2nd Firefox window

Tags: windows-10, firefox

For the last couple of days I have been unable to open a 2nd window without closing the one open.

I click the Firefox icon that usually opens a list of options containing .. Open new window, Open new tab...etc.

In windows 7 I used to not have to go through all of this...just clicked it and another window opened.

Now, there's just another layer of trouble and delay and additional things that can go wrong.

Windows 10 has an irritating little side pane that opens up, at times blocking something that needs to be seen on the page.

But, now, with nothing happening when I try to open a second window, I have to close the first and then, get the code my insurance company was sending me, then go back and fill in the form all over again.

How come when you get a script or an intruding website that needs to be stopped, when you go to processes you have 50 there that you don't even recognize and can't find the one that used to be running on top of the list without playing detective again?

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

Create a shortcut.

First **click** the **firefox** icon and hit **properties**.

and select the path Example below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\
```

Now paste the path in the shortcut.

*To Create a shortcut.*

**Right click** and select **New**. Then **Shortcut**.

Paste the path and name it.

Now when you click it you will have a new window like you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can't open a new firefox window when firefox is already running in windows 10.

When firefox is running, if I right-click on firefox logo in the taskbar, I can see the following menu.

[image: Context menu for firefox]

Here, if I select "Open new window", I can open a new firefox window. In your case, the menu should not be much different - and you should be able to open a new window from that menu as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We may try "Ctrl+N" shortcut keys to open a 2nd Fierfox window.

If the problem still persists, I suppose that Firefox is "hanging at exit" and is usually caused by an Extension or a Plugin.

Please refer to the link and check if it helps.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/833840